# Errors when connecting to MySQL local database

Tags: mysql, database, windows, database-connection

So, I have my local database, set it up, ran it from the windows services window. I open MySQL Workbench, and try to connect to the server. Hostname is 
`localhost` and username is `root`. I get something along the lines of `access denied error`. I try and run `mysql.exe -u root -p`.

It requires the password, I enter it, I get `access denied` error. I try adding `--skip-grant-tables`. I get a `Can not perform keyring migration` error. I try to run `mysqld`, and get `keyring migration failed`. I add `--defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"` and it tells me

```
mysqld: File '.\binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

And I have no idea what to do. 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am just reinstalling MySQL

After a reinstall I am still getting the `Can not perform keyring migration` error.

Now I can't even run the service after a reinstall

Comment: Please write the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I had to delete the data folder, run --initialize, then run mysqld -u mysql.

Comment: How does one run `--initialize`?

Comment: Run mysqld (normal args) --initialize in cmd prompe in the mysql server folder (wherever mysqld is)

Comment: I am having the same issue if I run initialize I get: mysqld --initialize
2019-10-29T17:21:57.234659Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) initializing of server in progress as process 166186
2019-10-29T17:21:57.237268Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-10-29T17:21:57.237282Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /storage/resources/dbase/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

Comment: Starting MySQL Server...
Oct 29 10:23:10 snorlax mysqld: mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Comment: Did you delete the data folder and rerun it? Make sure MySQL has permission to use it also.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have tried the accepted answer with no success. With the following error.

mysqld: Can't create directory 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Delete the data folder and make sure you run cmd as administrator before moving to the directory and running the initialize process.

It caused me a lot of time.